# Combine validated date and non-validated data to store in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, store, laravel-5.6

Here i have two inputs field as name and age.

I wanna validate **name** but not **age**.

How can i send both value to store.

```
request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
]);

//Here i wanna add 'age' along with 'name' in $request
//Then i must store.

Pastor::create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$request->all()` already sends whatever is in your request. But if you like you can specifically pass request values to create method like this:

```
Pastor::create([
   'name'=> $request->name,
   'age' => $request->age
   //any other fields
]);
```

I assume you have named your inputs like i have passed into create method and it should work.

Comment: Even my code working Mr.Haider Ali, i wanna store age without validate

Comment: @SamuelHenry Yes so the code is right, you haven't passed age field to validator rules array to be validated. And passed it directly to create method. SO its non validated

Answer (score 0):

use the Validator class Laravel has. lets say you have `UserController`

```
Use Validator;
Use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // Your Validator
    protected function yourValidatorName(array $data)
    {
        $rules = ['name'=>'required'];
        return Validator::make($data,$rules);;
    }

    // Your Main Function
    public function yourFunctionName(Request $request)
    {
        $isValid = $this->yourValidatorName($request->all());
        if(!isValid->fails())
        {
            // your code here (validation passed)
        }
        else
        {
             // your code here (validation failed)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even my code working Mr.Demonyowh, i wanna store age without validate. Hope you got me

Comment: yep .. that's why we validated the name .. but not the age .. look at the `$rules` variable ..

Answer (score 0):

You simply put a check on name field  only

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:200',
    ],[
        'name.required' => 'name is a required field.',       // custom messages you can omit them 
        'name.min' => ' Name must be at least 3 characters.',  // custom message for minimum characters 
        'name.max' => ' Name should not be greater than 200 characters.', // custom message for maximum characters 
    ]);
Pastor::create($request->all());
```

Without custom messages

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required|min:3|max:200',
]);
Pastor::create($request->all());
```

Comment: Even my code working Mr.Faizan Fayaz, i wanna store age without validate. Hope you got me –

Comment: So don't put any validations on age field  neither on frontend  nor on backend